# Why I can replace @RestContoller with @Component and it still works?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

Can someone explain why replacement of **RestController** annotation with **Component** has no any visible effect in my case?
My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/employees")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @PostMapping("")
    public Employee saveEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return employeeService.save(employee);
    }


    ...
```

This works in the same way:

```
@Component
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/api/employees")
public class EmployeeController {

...
```

Comment: What do you mean when you're talking "still works"? Spring context run succefully? Or your servlet paths is available still?

Comment: @DmitriiBykov yes, context runs successfully and servlet paths are still available too. I actually googled my question before, but most of answers look like "If you annotate controller as component Spring will automatically recognize it as a contoller via RequestMapping annotation. So, controller is just like component, but it has SOME additional functionality". But what is the additional functionality is it?

Comment: Annotations Repository Component Controller RestController are beans but Controller will return View for MVC, RestController will return json because this annotation incapsulates ResponseBody and Repository bean will wrape typical database exceptions. In older versions of Spring Conroller and RestController were also marker annotations for Spring factory fot macking URL after start Spring application

Answer (score 0):

The not-in-depth description of individual annotations would be:

- `@RequestMapping` registers your class for servlet mapping.
- `@Component` registers your class for dependency injection.
- `@ResponseBody` will add the return value of the method to the HTTP response body.

***1st case*** - `@RestController` registers your class for DI and adds `@ResponseBody` annotation to it, `@RequestMapping` registers class for servlet mapping.

***2nd case*** - `@Component` registers your class for DI and you added a manual `@ResponseBody` annotation to it, `@RequestMapping` registers class for servlet mapping.

Both of the cases above do the same thing, so that's why it 'just works'.